# How to know loaded window is Firefox Electrolysis Window

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

I want to code a functionality for Firefox Electrolysis window. But how can I know loaded window is Firefox Electrolysis window but not the normal Firefox window?

```
var WindowListener = {
    setupBrowserUI: function(window) {
        //
    },
    tearDownBrowserUI: function(window) {
    },
    // nsIWindowMediatorListener functions
    onOpenWindow: function(xulWindow) {
        var domWindow = xulWindow.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                                 .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);
        // Wait for it to finish loading
        domWindow.addEventListener("load", function listener() {
            domWindow.removeEventListener("load", listener, false);
            // If this is a browser window then setup its UI      
            if (domWindow.document.documentElement.getAttribute("windowtype")=="navigator:browser") {

                    //how to know domWindow is Firefox Electrolysis window

            }

        }, false);
    },
    onCloseWindow: function(xulWindow) {
    },
    onWindowTitleChange: function(xulWindow, newTitle) {
    }
};

let wm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].
       getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
// Wait for any new browser windows to open
wm.addListener(WindowListener);
```

You can use the code in Scratchpad. The comment

```
//how to know domWindow is Firefox Electrolysis window
```

is the place that I need to detect loaded window is Firefox Electrolysis window but not the normal Firefox window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");

var myObserver = function(subject, topic, data){
  if(subject.gMultiProcessBrowser){
    //electrolysis
  }
  else{
    //oxidation
  }
};

Services.obs.addObserver(myObserver, "browser-delayed-startup-finished", false);

//Since your restartless addon can be disabled, removed or updated
//remember to remove it during cleanup
Services.obs.removeObserver(myObserver, "browser-delayed-startup-finished", false)
```

Comment: Thanks but xulwindow.gMultiProcessBrowser is false for the e10s window as the code shows: [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7859558/)

Comment: Apparently for newly opened windows you have to setup an observer for the `browser-delayed-startup-finished` topic, and when the observer is fired check the value of `gMultiProcessBrowser`

Comment: Thanks again. Would you mind sharing the code that combines browser-delayed-startup-finished and window listener please? I am pretty new to Firefox coding.