# Can javascript detect presence of firefox electrolysis?

Tags: javascript, firefox

My question is similar to the one here [How to know loaded window is Firefox Electrolysis Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24959275/how-to-know-loaded-window-is-firefox-electrolysis-window)

Except I'm not writing an add-on, just a script to execute on a page, so I don't think I can use the solution there.

I'd really just like to know if asynchronous scrolling is active or not.  Is it possible?

Comment: a good question, i would like to know this too